# I'm trying to get the value of the input to the label field in the QR generator code but not sure where I'm going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Trying to make a dynamic change along with the input that we type, there is a change in the input field .
Or
Once we submit the input, we get a change in the label?
How can we approach it? I am trying to pass the input value but something is wrong

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// $(".demo").qrcode({
//     text: 'https://www.jqueryscript.net'
//  });


var input = document.querySelector('.input');
var data = input.value;



  $(".demo").qrcode({

    // 0: normal
    // 1: label strip
    // 2: label box
    mode: 1,
    label: "{{name}}",
    fontname: 'sans',
    fontcolor: '#000'
    
  });

 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/qrcode@1.2.0/build/qrcode.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" class="input ng-model='name'">

<div class="demo">
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just checking, Goutham; what are you looking to change when you update your code?

Comment: I am trying to get the input value to show up in the  label: "{{name}}" field so it outputs in qr code @AaronMorefield

Comment: @AaronMorefield AFAICT you added the wrong QR Javascript lib in your edit of this question. OP's original code uses `dist/jquery-qrcode.js`, so clearly some kind of jQuery plugin/lib, [probably this one](https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/) as OP's code seems to match that syntax.  You have chosen a completely different lib in your edit, (and on top of that linked to a webpage, not JS source), so the code does not run and nobody can possibly OP. Can you clarify?  @gotham_learn can you confirm what QR lib you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't link to the QR lib you are using (and AFAICT someone else's edit of your question confused things even more by linking to a different, *wrong* QR lib) which makes things harder.  My guess is you are using [jQuery.qrcode](https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/).  For future reference you will make it easier for people to help you if you can clearly state what you are using, and create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - *working*, complete code which demonstrates your problem.

Next problem is you are using an ancient version of jQuery (1.12.4).  Is there a reason for that?  Whatever the reason, jQuery.qrcode does not work with that version of jQuery.  I tried jQuery 3.3.1, the latest version Stackoverflow snippets list, but that doesn't work either.  Finally I checked [the demo](https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/latest/demo/) linked from [the jQuery.qrcode home page](https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/), viewed that source, and found [they are using 3.5.1](https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/latest/demo/jquery.min.js).  And using that version in my snippet works!

So, now we finally have a working set of libraries, on to the actual question.

If you want to update the label dynamically, as you type, you'll need to add an event listener.  You could use [the `change()` event](https://api.jquery.com/change/), but for a text input that will fire only after you click away or hit enter - so you won't see live typing cause any updates.  If you want to see the label update live, as you type, [`keyup()`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) is the way to go, and I've used that below.

Your handler just needs to

- Get the current text;
- Remove the old QR code, otherwise you end up with one for each keypress on the page;
- Draw a new QR code with that new label;

Here's a working snippet - click Run to see it in action.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // The link "content" of the QR code, the actual message
    var text = 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/71073404/6089612';
    
    var demo = $('.demo');
    var input = $('.input');

    // Simple function to draw the QR code with the specified label
    function drawQR(label) {
        $(".demo").qrcode({
            mode: 1,
            label: label,
            text: text,
            fontname: 'sans',
            fontcolor: '#000'
        });
    }

    // Define an event handler that will fire every time a key is typed
    // in your input
    input.on('keyup', function() {
    
        // First get the current label text
        var label = $(this).val();
        
        // Now remove the existing QR code by emptying the div content
        demo.html('');
    
        // Finally redraw the QR with our new label
        drawQR(label);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lrsjng.jquery-qrcode/0.18.0/jquery-qrcode.min.js"></script>

Label: <input type="text" class="input ng-model='name'">

<div class="demo"></div>
```

Comment: That helped a lot to understand what is happening

Comment: thanks so much @Don't Panic